# Confused on importing

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot and I have a cogs folder and I have a help cog which has

```
from utils.util import Pag
```

But I get "Unable to import 'utils.util'" however in my moderation cog I have this exact line and I still get this error, but it works? I also have this line in my main file which also works just fine so not sure why it just won't work in the help cog and it's honestly just confusing me.

Not sure if this helps, but here's what the folder or directory (I think that's the correct term) looks like.

```
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── Rekka
|   ├── cogs
|   |   ├── __pycache__     

|   |   ├── error_handler.py
|   |   ├── fun.py
|   |   ├── giveaway.py     
|   |   ├── help.py
|   |   ├── logs.py
|   |   ├── moderation.py
|   |   ├── music.py
|   |   └── utility.py
|   ├── config
|   |   ├── config.json
|   |   └── secrets.json
|   ├── main.py
|   ├── old.py
|   └── utils
|      ├── __pycache__

|      ├── json_loader.py
|      ├── mongo.py
|      └── util.py
└── requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `cogs` and `utils` are siblings sub-modules under the `Rekka` module, you should try to use it's full namespace like:

`from Rekka.utils.util import Pag`

Otherwise, Python will try to find `utils` in the global namespace.

Comment: I've actually already tried this and I still get the same issue except it just says Unable to import 'Rekka.utils.util' and in the terminal it says ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'Rekka'

Comment: @ObviousQuantity try to add more information about your environment in the question, such as Python version and how you are trying to run the script from the terminal. Depending on the Python version, a `__init__.py` file is expected in order to recognize modules.

Comment: the python version is 3.9.2 and I'm coding this in Visual Studio Code and when running the code I just right click on main.py and click "run python file in terminal"

Comment: How are you importing things in `main.py`? Some inconsistency in the way imports are defined across the files until `help.py` may cause the issue. Also, have you tried to use relative imports with two dots (`..`). More information about it in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports